# when I try to paste jar files in lib folder (in eclipse) it gives the following error :

Tags: eclipse

when I try to paste jar files in lib folder (in eclipse) it gives the following error : cannot paste the clipboard contents into the selected elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot paste a .jar file directly until and unless jar files are extracted. Instead do this,

Project -> properties -> Java build path -> libraries -> add external jars

Answer (score 1):

Firstly do not paste the jars from a **ZIP** folder. Extract it and then copy and try pasting. It won't give cannot copy clipboard contents into selected elements then.

Answer (score -2):

Try moving all the JAR contents **outside the zip folder** that you have just downloaded and then copy all the contents to the specified folder of your eclipse project